# Drawing histogram from data in array

Tags: c++, arrays, histogram

I am attempting to write a function which takes an int array as argument, and writes a histogram with '*' for data in the array.

For example, for int arr[]{2,1,0,7,1,9}, we should get:

[image: histogram]

How should I write this code?

My code:

```
    using namespace std;

    int max = 0;
    char znak = '*';

    void histo(int arr[], size_t size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > max)
                max = arr[i];
        }

//drawing histogram

while (max > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (arr[i] >= max) {
                    cout << znak << " ";
                }
                else {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            max--;
        }

    }


    int main()
    {
        int arr[]{2,1,0,7,1,9};
        size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
        histo(arr, size);

    }
```

Comment: You 're missing the question ...

Comment: _"I have problem with drawing histogram"_ is not a valid problem statement. You need to tell us what you're attempting, what you're having problems with, what behavior you're expecting, what behavior you're observing, etc. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry. my bad. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the code should work

```
char znak = '*';

void histo(int arr[], size_t size) {

    //finding the top point of this hystogram
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    int level = max;
    int currSize =0;
    while (level != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            currSize = arr[i];
            if (currSize >= level) {
                cout << znak;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        level--;

        cout << "\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]{2,1,0,7,1,9};
    size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    histo(arr, size);

}
```

Because everything has to be printing at the same time, you want to make sure the * is only printed if the array says its supposed to print at that height.